# Setting cookies in rails with domain option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to set a cookie in one domain and access it from another.  Is this possible?

Here's what I'm doing in my app:

In a controller, the test action is accessed via this url:

**http://myapp.com/account/test**

```
def test
  cookies[:foo] = {
    :value => 'something',
    :domain => 'myapp.heroku.com'
  }
end
```

In same controller, the test2 action is accessed via this url:

**http://myapp.heroku.com/account/test2**

```
def test2 
  puts "foo=#{cookies[:foo]}"
end
```

but the value of cookies[:foo] is always blank.  Is it possible to access the cookie from the heroku.com domain.  I thought setting the :domain option would allow this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The :domain option (and setting domain on cookies in general) only really works across subdomains. i.e. for app1.mysite.com and app2.mysite.com - you could set the cookie domain to .mysite.com and have it shared between the sub-domains.

This is just how cookies are designed to work. myapp.com and myapp.heroku.com are separate domains, not sub-domains, so attempting to set the domain this way isn't going to work.

There are some ways to achieve true cross-domain cookies - but they are [rather involved.](http://www.theserverside.com/patterns/thread.tss?thread_id=31258)

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this for a different domain, but you can do it for subdomains. So, for instance,
an app running on domain `example.com` can set a cookie for `subdomain.example.com` but not for `exampleapp.com`.

I have to add, if it were possible to set cookies for other, arbitrary domains, there would be massive security/privacy issues.

You can set the same cookies for all your domains by doing the following in environment.rb:

```
 ActionController::CgiRequest::DEFAULT_SESSION_OPTIONS[:session_domain => '.mydomain.com']
```

see [here](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000277) for the documentation.

Comment: Also, it's possible that some browsers (or plugins) won't let your app do this... but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out http://coderack.org/users/ahamid/middlewares/142-session-injector